# Why the onclick function is called automatically once the website is rendered - Flask?

Tags: html, flask

I am using Flask to develop a web application. I wrote the function loginGmail in py and tried to call it by the onclick event of a button in html. However, the function was automatically called once the website is loaded.

main.py

```
def loginGmail():
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

The loginGmail() is passed to home.html at:

```
return render_template('home.html', things_to_sort=things_to_sort, form=form, loginGmailFunc=loginGmail)
```

At html's side:

```
<button id="login" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="() => this.{{loginGmailFunc()}}">Login</button>
```